# error in deleting row in grid in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have displayed some data in a grid format and now I am trying to delete the row on click of delete button in last row but I am getting error. Can someone please suggest me what mistake I am making. My Code:

```
<form action="deleteQuote.php" method="post">
            <?php
                require_once('config.php');
                $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) 
                or die ('Cannot connect to db');
                $result = $conn->query("SELECT quoteid,name,quote FROM `quotes`, category WHERE category.catid = quotes.catid and quotes.isactive = 1");
                echo "<table>";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='delete_id' value=$row[quoteid] /></td> <td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[quote]</td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value='Delete' /></td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            ?>
            </form>
```

deleteQuote.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete_id']) && !empty($_POST['delete_id'])){
    require_once('config.php');
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) 
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');
    $delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']);
    echo "DELETE FROM quotes WHERE quoteid =".$delete_id;
    $result = $conn->query("DELETE FROM quotes WHERE quoteid =".$delete_id);

}
header('Location: quotes.php');
```

?>

I am getting following error:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/38/11053638/html/admin/deleteQuote.php on line 6
>   Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/content/38/11053638/html/admin/deleteQuote.php on line 6
>   DELETE FROM quotes WHERE quoteid =
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/38/11053638/html/admin/deleteQuote.php:6) in /home/content/38/11053638/html/admin/deleteQuote.php on line 11

Comment: You have db connection issue show us config.php

Comment: You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`. Never do that

Comment: @chandresh_cool config.php seems fine as i am displaying the data in grid using same file

Comment: mysql-real-escape-string requires a open mysql connection (in the current namespace (?)).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you haven't opened a mysql connection. You're using mysqli instead of mysql, so you need to use the equivalent mysqli method.

Change:

```
$delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']);
```

to:

```
$delete_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']);
```

However, since mysqli supports prepared statements, you should use that instead of concatenating strings. Then you don't have to worry about escaping the string.